# ASP.NET 3.5: What could cause a session to timeout prematurely?

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

We have our session set to timeout after 120 minutes.  Recently, however, one of the production servers has been encountering a ton of problems.  Since I have no access to the server box itself, I am working on limited information here.  We have two servers on which our website is deployed.  Sever A works fine all of the time, but server B is constantly having these expired session issues.  This has been recent, like as of the past two weeks.

I know I am not providing enough information to pinpoint the problem directly, but what are some issues that could cause the session to be reset with no rhyme or reason?

Comment: Are you using some kind of load-balancing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, I fixed it.  I opened the IIS7 application pool advanced settings for both servers side by side and noticed one difference:  The `Regular Time Interval` setting was 5 on server A and 1740 on server B.  I changed server A's setting to 1740 (the default) and the problems stopped immediately.

Oddly, this started occurring right when the server admins did a roll-back to a month ago.  Something got jacked up somehow and these settings must have gotten changed.

While I still don't fully understand how what I did fixed things, either it was just a coincidence or that low 5-minute setting was the problem.

If anyone cares to shed light on this then, by all means, do so.

Answer (score 1):

The app pool may be recycling for one of a number of reasons. There are a number of settings and exceeding any of them will cause ASP.NET to recycle:

1. Recycle worker processes (in minutes)
2. Recycle worker process (in requests)
3. Recycle worker processes at the following times
4. Maximum virtual memory
5. Maximum used memory

If you're using in-proc session state, the sessions will be lost if the app pool recycles.

If no settings have been changed, it's most likely that you're suffering from memory issues, maybe due to a memory leak (which may not be a 'real' leak, but references held when they should be released).

You say that you're using two servers. If session state is being lost, it sounds like you're using in-proc session state. In which case, I presume you're using load balancing with 'sticky sessions' (where subsequent requests go to the same server)?

If I'm wrong and you're using shared state (such as SQL Server Session State Provider or State Server), could it be that the clocks are out-of-sync on your servers?

Comment: Yes, two load-balanced servers.  I've never heard of the term "in-process" session before, but it uses server memory for the session rather than a database table.  I am going to have to research a bit more on items 1-3, but for 4 and 5, are these based on hardware and/or OS configuration or something set in the web.config?  In other words, if the server has 8gb RAM, is there a max virtual/used memory setting in the web.config that would override that?

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind:

As @Steve Morgan said, if you are using in-process sessions and "sticky" sessions, then it could be caused by a problem in the load balancer.  When load balancing, sessions should always be out-of-process because, quite frankly, "sticky" doesn't mean sessions won't bounce between the two machines.  It just means it's less likely to.  If the load balancer is overloaded then the users will be sent to a different server than the first one.

App Pool Recycling is another cause of lost sessions; again due to using in-process session management.  If you move to out-of-process it will *hide* the problem.  The real issue here though needs investigated as it will almost always be the result of bad code.

My guess is that you've got a combination of issues.  Start with moving to out-of-process sessions and set up a state server.  This will get past the immediate pain.  Then start looking at both the balancer and the web server logs to see if you need a better balancer or need to make code changes to plug the memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Have any new sites been put up on your server recently?
We came across this problem when transferring to .net 4 and didn't think to create a new App Pool for the new .net 4 sites (as a opposed to the .net 2/3.5 ones). 
This caused the app pool to constantly restart as they can't run under the same app pool.

Also have you uploaded any new code that may be getting its self stuck in a loop, this could also crash the app pool, causing the session to restart?

Another thought.. do you have any updates waiting to install on this server.. this has also created unexplained problems.

Answer (score -1):

Working solution:

1. start "**ASP.NET State Server**" in your services (make it Automatic, so it always starts)
2. add this to your **web.config**  (copy as is!):

> ```
> <system.web>
>     <sessionState mode="StateServer"
>       stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"
>       cookieless="false"
>       timeout="60" />
>     <machineKey validationKey="DCB7132A24938F2166E362214ADAD861FA6B819E0A337F0E63257F87014A37B5EBC5D9F9AD107C38E3D3378BC35CBAF81407F3E4D8BA430FD65348DDCC469623" decryptionKey="DD09731F76271B2AAE6AE957626F8D1B8E3CBF11EF8E3CDDF01332CDF914D4B5" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
> </system.web>
> ```

**note: or generate you own machine key: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

---

Now you can recycle your application pool, modify your web.config, or restart your web service - and the sessions are in place!
Now you can also enable web gardens in the pools to gain more performance.